# Adding Footnotes to conference poster

Tags: footnotes, beamerposter

I'm using the Jacobs Landscape poster template (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster) for a project poster. The requirement it that all references are given in footnotes. I would like to reference using the [ABC] to represent the paper with authors Adams, Brooks and Craig (don't remember what this type of referencing is called sorry). I've tried using \footfullcite commands but the whole 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns disappear off into the eather. I'm pretty new to LaTeX and am at a loss as to what else to try.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

The code I have tried (edited to the bits I *think* are necessary :S) is as follows:

```
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns

\begin{frame}[t] 
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column
\begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column

\begin{block}{Introduction}
As seen in \footfullcite{[GNP]}
\end{block}

\end{column}
```

Comment: Footnotes are numbered in general, so using [ABC] is a bit strange. A poster summarizes a large topic in small blocks, think of them as pages. Where do footnotes go? On the bottom of each block/page? Or rather at a block/page of its own? Or at a place below pages/blocks, coming together with the background, the matrix. What i am questioning here is: Who requires footnotes on a poster?

Comment: This type of referencing is used in all of the literature surrounding the topic of my project. I think what I'm trying to do is write in footnote size across the bottom of the poster, crossing the boundry of the columns. More to create the illution of footnotes.

Comment: Word of advice: Don't do it. Use a block of its own at the very end, i.e. the bottom-right corner.

Comment: Do you really have brackets in your citekeys? Footnotes and `beamer` are a crazy mix. Since a poster requires manually putting stuff, put `fullcite`s at the appropriate places.